# The animate callback function called immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, jquery-animate

I am using the below line to blink  a block. It works but the callback function `incre()` is called immediately and does not wait till blinking is over.

I need to call `incre()` only after the animate function blinks 2 seconds. What am I missing?

```
block.attr({ opacity: 0.3 }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000,incre());
```

Comment: Note that to format a block of code on SO indent it by four spaces (or select the code and click the `{}` button) - don't use '>', which creates a block quote.

Comment: got it..Will follow from here on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you are attempting [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) sounds like a good choice

```
block.fadeTo(2000, 0.3, function() {
    block.fadeTo(2000, 1);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdfFQ/)

However, the error in your codes are:

- the **`()`** (*Brackets* after the callback function name) i.e. `incre()`
- `opacity` is a CSS property not an attribute. so user `.css()` to manipulate them

The correct codes are:

```
block
   .css({ opacity: 0.3 })
   .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 2000, incre);
```

#### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gdfFQ/1/)

Comment: `opacity` is actually an Raphael-supported attribute -- it controls fill-opacity and stroke-opacity at the same time.  Therefore, passing it as a parameter to animate is not really an error.  However, `fadeTo` is certainly more appropriate =)

Comment: Thanks a lot..I agree even though animate worked it did not give ths same feeling like blink...fade in looks more appropriate.